# get Response from Firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've created a cloud functions in `firebase` and I want to get response of the functions back to Android app.
`Cloud functions` is written in `typescript` and is like

```
exports.validateOtp = functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=>{
   phoneNumber = req.query.phoneNumber;
   otp = req.query.otp;   
   getVal();
   function getVal(){
   let result = authFunction.userValidation(phoneNumber,otp).then(function(boolResult){
     return res.status(204).send(result);
   });
   }
 });
```

How can I fetch the value of `result` at client side or android app?

Answer (score 1):

Since your Cloud Function is an HTTPS one it will be triggered when you send an HTTP request (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and OPTIONS) to the function endpoint.

In your case the function endpoint URL will be

```
https://us-central1-<your-project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/validateOtp
```

see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#invoke_an_http_function

There are several possible ways to send an HTTP request from an Android app to an HTTP endpoint. You could use the [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) library, the [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library or the [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) one, for example.

---

Note that it may be interesting to switch to an **HTTPS Callable Cloud Function** instead of a "simple" HTTPS Cloud Function.

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), "the Cloud Functions for Firebase client SDKs let you call functions directly from a Firebase app. To call a function from your app in this way, write and deploy an HTTPS Callable function in Cloud Functions".

Among the advantages offered by HTTPS Callable functions you will find the fact that it "automatically deserializes the request body", that it "validates auth tokens" as well as the fact that you don't need to use an extra library to call the Function, but just to use the code detailed in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function).